# threading - thread isn't executing

Tags: python

I'm learning threading in Python and tried to create a threading program as shown below

```
def main():
    print('Hello world!')

if __name__ == "__main__"
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=main)
```

However when changing the target=main(), it executes but some parts of my code don't work then
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a variable `thread1` the thread which **prepares the thread**(clarification needed, am not sure exactly) to execute the function `main()`. To execute it just run `thread1.start()` and done!

Comment: Because you might want to set some parameters before you start the thread, or you might want to create a number of threads and then start them all at once.

Comment: Okay thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just add `thread1.start()` and your thread should execute! (If you need to pass arguments to the target function, add `args=(your, arguments, here)`)